# Is it possible to invoke OCaml from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ocaml

Is it possible to use OCaml with .NET code?

I would like to invoke it like C++. Or maybe there a bridge for it.

Comment: So you want to run the interpreter to execute your ocaml code?  You want to embed it?  Have you tried using F# to run your ocaml code?  F# derived from ocaml so there's a good chance it might work.

Comment: I don't want to run ocaml code. I want to execute some functions from compiled library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered [CSML](http://www.lexifi.com/csml)?  You would need to write a bit in its interface description language, and then should be able to call from .NET to OCaml and vice versa.