# It's possible to integrate OCaml library function in c#(.net tecnology) project?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, ocaml

It is possible to use **OCaml library** functions in a project .net framework (WindowsForm, C#, etc.). 
Call function passing parameters and receiving an answer.

For example, there are plug-ins for Visual-Studio?

P.S.
I know F# but my question is specific, if it is possible to integrate **OCaml library** in **.net framework** applications.

Eventually it would be nice to have examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592451/is-it-possible-to-invoke-ocaml-from-net

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LexiFi [did this](http://www.lexifi.com/csml). I have no affiliations, so maybe someone from LexiFI can give more information. But the link is actually quite informative.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, CSML might the tool you are looking for.  It supports calling .Net from OCaml and OCaml from .Net.  It requires to write manually some specification of the bridge (to choose name of bound components, calling conventions, etc) but the specification is then statically type-checked.  The public release of CSML is not actively maintained, though, only because of the absence of interest from the community.  We (LexiFi) use it internally quite a lot to build our Windows applications, and if there is interest from the community, we will update the public version.