# Use libraries written in OCaml in VSTO C# Office solutions

Tags: c#, dll, ocaml, vsto, ffi

(* I would like to re-ask a question ([Is it possible to invoke OCaml from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592451/is-it-possible-to-invoke-ocaml-from-net)), because the solution proposed (CSML) does not look enough for me. *)

Previously, I have written a computational library written in OCaml.

Now, I want to write an [Office solution by VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-solutions-development-overview-vsto?view=vs-2017) in C#, that makes use of this library written in OCaml.

There are several tools around that may achieve this:

- [ocamlbuild](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc#advanced-targets)
- [ctypes](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes)
- [csml](https://github.com/LexiFi/csml)

Does anyone know which one (or some others) suits best my need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to invoke OCaml from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592451/is-it-possible-to-invoke-ocaml-from-net)

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia I just edited the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used VSTO myself, but from the documentation page [architecture of VSTO add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/architecture-of-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2017) it looks like the add-ins are normal .NET managed assemblies packaged with some additional metadata. This suggests that you could have a main assembly in a .NET language such as C#, developed using the Visual Studio tools, that interacts with an OCaml codebase using CSML as a bridge.

You could try doing this by creating a simple "hello world" VSTO add-in, that internally invokes a simple "hello world" example of CSML usage to call a very simple OCaml library. If this doesn't work, I would suggest asking the CSML people directly for advice; if it does work, you could send them the example for them to describe/integrate in their documentation.